# How to show and hide a password in a secure way using PDO

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, pdo

Good Day,

I would like to show a password stored in SQL-Server and display it once clicked on the button.
When the button is clicked a request must be made by using PDO. How would I go and do this in a secure way by storing the passwords encrypted in SQL Server and decrypting the password once clicked by the user?

What also would be nice is to add a button to edit this input field so that the user can update this password if they have the required permission.

I will add steps to keep an audit of who viewed the password.

For example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Change Input Text Value OnClick Event</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="my_field" value="***********">
<button onclick="change()">Show Password</button>
<script>
function change(){
    var txt = "My Password"; // get this value using php, what would the best way be toencrypt and decrypt passwords
    document.getElementById("my_field").value = txt;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**password_verify example**

```
// See the password_hash() example to see where this came from.
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Comment: If the password is securely stored to begin with ( ie: hashed ) then you can only rely upon client side code and the browser to autofill the password. From that point change the form element `type` attribute from `password` to `text`?

Comment: passwords can be securely stored in a database using a one-way hashing algorithm, you can use: [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). To verify a password, use: [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: Because I want to be able for users to store passwords and then be able to come back and view the passwords, as here is an example of what password_verify would do, this function only returns true or false if I am correct. Added code snippet to the description

Comment: I would be remiss if I didn't mention [OWASP's password storage](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html) recommendations, specifically _In the context of password storage, encryption should only be used in edge cases where it is necessary to obtain the original plaintext password._ There used to even be a dedicated website for "plain text offenders" (not going to link to it) where people would publicly shame sites that stored passwords in plain text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found something that I was looking for.

Unfortunately will not be able to use the password hashing method, so I would need to create my encryption and decryption function by using "openssl_encrypt()" and found this article from geeksforgeeks.com and it explains the process.

I will then just modify and encrypt between SQL and PHP to make this work in the way I want it to.

Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string/

Example Code

```
<?php

// Store a string into the variable which
// need to be Encrypted
$simple_string = "Welcome to GeeksforGeeks\n";

// Display the original string
echo "Original String: " . $simple_string;

// Store the cipher method
$ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";

// Use OpenSSl Encryption method
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
$options = 0;

// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for encryption
$encryption_iv = '1234567891011121';

// Store the encryption key
$encryption_key = "GeeksforGeeks";

// Use openssl_encrypt() function to encrypt the data
$encryption = openssl_encrypt($simple_string, $ciphering,
            $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);

// Display the encrypted string
echo "Encrypted String: " . $encryption . "\n";

// Non-NULL Initialization Vector for decryption
$decryption_iv = '1234567891011121';

// Store the decryption key
$decryption_key = "GeeksforGeeks";

// Use openssl_decrypt() function to decrypt the data
$decryption=openssl_decrypt ($encryption, $ciphering,
        $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv);

// Display the decrypted string
echo "Decrypted String: " . $decryption;

?>
```